# Difference in number of lines in Editpad Lite and Windows notepad

Tags: c#, notepad

I have a text file which when opened in Editpad Lite show the number of lines as 2754813 and when it is opened in Windows Notepad showing the number of lines as 2713520. When I read it with a C# programme, it shows the number of lines contained in the text file as 2713520 i.e. the same as in notepad. Wordwrap is turned off in both cases This prevents me from matching the lines with Editpad text file. Would anyone please offer their valuable comment.

Comment: Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: why you need to use the Editpad Lite ? if the line number on notepad is same as C# application so what the problem ? can you try to use  notepad++ ?

Comment: Editpad Lite open (even with big files) in a second while the Windows Notepad on my laptop take several minutes or sometimes fail to open. That is the reason why I use Editpad Lite.

Comment: At last I succeeded to an extent. It was not possible for me to capture each line with \r\n or \n with C# Regex. I used the line-break symbol itself from word document. But the trouble is I cannot see the symbol I have used.

Answer (score 0):

```
int b = 0;
using (StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(path_to_textfile.txt"))
{
  using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(lisfile))
  {
    while ((line = Reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
      Match match = Regex.Match(line, @"");//line break symbol between quotes.
      if (match.Success)
      {
        b++;
        if (b == 100000) //I got the count of lines correctly.
        {
          Writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        //Writer.WriteLine(line);
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this way, I can hope to get the line count correctly when reading the file programmatically. However the problem I faced as in the post still exists with Editpad Lite. It no longer bothers me!

Comment: I have also emailed the problem to vendor. But they are yet to respond because this is a free version that I am using. Thanks to @Hans Passant

Comment: I got a feedbak from the Editpad Lite people clarifying that while Notepad only supports CRLF line breaks, EditPad supports all Unicode 
line breaks.which accounts for the difference in the count of lines because the text file in questio may be having line breaks other than CRLF.